# jquery-select2 - add select2 to existing dropdown code to make searchable

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I have two dropdown select boxes that result in details of two careers being displayed in side-by-side columns of a table. The code has been edited down taking many of the actual options out for ease of use and modification. It works fine currently except there will be over 300 values to choose from which is a lot of scrolling. Therefore, I'd like to make the dorpdowns searchable. The two best options I've come across are Select2 and Chosen.

I can't seem to get Select2 or Chosen to work (i.e. does not make the dropdowns searchable). I've tried both and must be doing something wrong. I can get them to work if I start a jsfiddle from scratch but I can't seem to add it to my current code. I guess I'm just not sure how to integrate it into my current code. I've stripped out my attempts to show the code I'm starting with. Any help on where/how I should add Select2 to my two existing drop downs would be appreciated.

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1arbb396/1/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <p>
    Search over 300 careers below:
    </p>
    <p>Career One:
    <br>

    <select name="" id="my-select"></select>
    </p>
    <p>
    Career Two:
    <br>
    <select name="" id="my-select-2"></select>
    </p>

<table id="my-table" border="1" style="width:100%">
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

  </body>
```

And the JS half...

```
    var myCareerInfo = {
  careers: [
  {
    name: 'Choose A Career',
    id: 100,
    careerInfo: {
      description: '',
      requiredEd: '',
      salary: '',
      curentJobs: '',
      jobGrowth: '',
      jobChange: '',
      category: '',
    }
  }, 
{
    name: 'Aerospace Engineering and Operations Technicians',
    id: 101,
    careerInfo: {
      description: 'Aerospace engineering and operations technicians operate and maintain equipment used in developing, testing, and producing new aircraft and spacecraft. Increasingly, these workers are using computer-based modeling and simulation tools and processes in their work.',
      requiredEd: 'Associate\'s degree',
      salary: '$66,180',
      curentJobs: '11,400',
      jobGrowth: '4% (Slower than average)',
      jobChange: '400',
      category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
    }
  }, 
{
    name: 'Agricultural Engineers',
    id: 103,
    careerInfo: {
      description: 'Agricultural engineers attempt to solve agricultural problems concerning power supplies, the efficiency of machinery, the use of structures and facilities, pollution and environmental issues, and the storage and processing of agricultural products.',
      requiredEd: 'Bachelor\'s degree',
      salary: '$75,090',
      curentJobs: '2,900',
      jobGrowth: '4% (Slower than average)',
      jobChange: '100',
      category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
    }
  }, 
{
    name: 'Architects',
    id: 104,
    careerInfo: {
      description: 'Architects plan and design houses, factories, office buildings, and other structures.',
      requiredEd: 'Bachelor\'s degree',
      salary: '$76,100',
      curentJobs: '112,600',
      jobGrowth: '7% (As fast as average)',
      jobChange: '7,800',
      category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
    }
  }
  ]
}

function populateSelectBoxes($select, data) {
  var careers = [];
  $.each(data, function() {
    careers.push('<option value="'+this.id+'">' + this.name + '</option>');
  });
  $select.append(careers.join(''));
  return $select; // Return populated select box.
}

function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectBoxes) {
  var career = [];

  selectBoxes.map(function(s){
        var currentId = s.val();
      return data.map(function(item){
            if(item.id == currentId) career.push(item);
      })
  });
  /* Comment out if you need to permit empty or unvalid selections
  while(career.length < 2)career.push({
    name: "",
    careerInfo: {
      salary: "",
      education: "",
      skills: "",
      description: "",
    }
  })
  //*/


  $tableBody.html('<tr>'+
                                    '<th style="width 10%"></th>'+
                     '<th style="width:45%">' + career[0].name + '</th>'+
                     '<th style="width:45%">' + career[1].name + '</th>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Salary</th>'+
                     '<td style="width:45%">' + career[0].careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '<td style="width:45%">' + career[1].careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Entry Level Education</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.requiredEd + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.requiredEd + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Career Description</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Number Of Current Jobs</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.curentJobs + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.curentJobs + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Job Growth</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.jobGrowth + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.jobGrowth + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Job Change</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.jobChange + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.jobChange + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<th>Category</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.category + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.category + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'
                     );


}

var selectBoxes = [
  populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select'), myCareerInfo.careers),
  populateSelectBoxes($('#my-select-2'), myCareerInfo.careers),
]

$('#my-select').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});


$('#my-select-2').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});
```

Comment: "I can't get it to work properly" is not helpful. What are the expected results by which you define "working properly", and what are your actual results (e.g. what is it doing that it is not supposed to, or vice-versa)?

Comment: @MJH I guess "properly" shouldn't have been included. I can't get it to work at all. The problem is me, not select2. I think I'm trying to insert the code in the wrong spot perhaps. I can get select2 to work if I start from scratch but I'm not sure how to add it to my existing code. Is that more clear?

Comment: Yes, a bit. Could you post a link to the working fiddle (the "start from scratch" one)?

Comment: @MJH https://jsfiddle.net/juL1t9k6/ is simply an example from a tutorial that I modified to make sure I could get Select2 to work. Other than changing the names to be careers instead of countries, it has no relation to my main project (so I don't think it will help much). I have no idea how to combine the two. Sorry I'm a noob. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var myCareerInfo = {
    careers: [
        {
            text: 'Choose A Career',
            id: 100,
            careerInfo: {
                description: '',
                requiredEd: '',
                salary: '',
                curentJobs: '',
                jobGrowth: '',
                jobChange: '',
                category: '',
            }
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Aerospace Engineering and Operations Technicians',
            id: 101,
            careerInfo: {
                description: 'Aerospace engineering and operations technicians operate and maintain equipment used in developing, testing, and producing new aircraft and spacecraft. Increasingly, these workers are using computer-based modeling and simulation tools and processes in their work.',
                requiredEd: 'Associate\'s degree',
                salary: '$66,180',
                curentJobs: '11,400',
                jobGrowth: '4% (Slower than average)',
                jobChange: '400',
                category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
            }
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Agricultural Engineers',
            id: 103,
            careerInfo: {
                description: 'Agricultural engineers attempt to solve agricultural problems concerning power supplies, the efficiency of machinery, the use of structures and facilities, pollution and environmental issues, and the storage and processing of agricultural products.',
                requiredEd: 'Bachelor\'s degree',
                salary: '$75,090',
                curentJobs: '2,900',
                jobGrowth: '4% (Slower than average)',
                jobChange: '100',
                category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
            }
        }, 
        {
            text: 'Architects',
            id: 104,
            careerInfo: {
                description: 'Architects plan and design houses, factories, office buildings, and other structures.',
                requiredEd: 'Bachelor\'s degree',
                salary: '$76,100',
                curentJobs: '112,600',
                jobGrowth: '7% (As fast as average)',
                jobChange: '7,800',
                category: 'Architecture and Engineering',
            }
        }
    ]
}

$('#my-select').select2({
  data: myCareerInfo.careers
});

$('#my-select-2').select2({
  data: myCareerInfo.careers
});

var career = [{ id: 0, text: 'Physical Therapist' }, { id: 1, text: 'Another Career' }, { id: 2, text: 'Security Guard' }];
$('select#career').select2({
  data: career
});

function populateTableRow($tableBody, data, selectBoxes) {
  var career = [];

  selectBoxes.map(function(s){
        var currentId = s.val();
      return data.map(function(item){
            if(item.id == currentId) career.push(item);
      })
  });
  /* Comment out if you need to permit empty or unvalid selections
  while(career.length < 2)career.push({
    name: "",
    careerInfo: {
      salary: "",
      education: "",
      skills: "",
      description: "",
    }
  })
  //*/

  $tableBody.html('<tr>'+
                                    '<th style="width 10%"></th>'+
                     '<th style="width:45%">' + career[0].name + '</th>'+
                     '<th style="width:45%">' + career[1].name + '</th>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Salary</th>'+
                     '<td style="width:45%">' + career[0].careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '<td style="width:45%">' + career[1].careerInfo.salary +'</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Entry Level Education</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.requiredEd + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.requiredEd + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Career Description</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.description + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Number Of Current Jobs</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.curentJobs + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.curentJobs + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Job Growth</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.jobGrowth + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.jobGrowth + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<tr>' +
                     '<th>Job Change</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.jobChange + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.jobChange + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'+ 
                     '<th>Category</th>'+
                     '<td>' + career[0].careerInfo.category + '</td>'+
                     '<td>' + career[1].careerInfo.category + '</td>'+
                     '</tr>'
                     );
}

var selectBoxes = [
  $('#my-select'),
  $('#my-select-2'),
];

$('#my-select').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});


$('#my-select-2').change(function() {
  populateTableRow($('#my-table tbody'), myCareerInfo.careers, selectBoxes);
});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Search over 300 careers below:
    </p>
    <p>Career One:
        <br>
        <select name="" id="my-select"></select>
    </p>
    <p>
        Career Two:
        <br>
        <select name="" id="my-select-2"></select>
    </p>
    <table id="my-table" border="1" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for your time!